# Can I rely on the serialization of two identical structures being identical?

Tags: rust, serde

Consider the following code:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
   a: u32,
   b: u32
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "MyStruct")]
struct AlsoMyStruct {
   a: u32,
   b: u32
}
```

I am wondering if I can safely do something like:

```rust
let ser = any_encoding::serialize(&MyStruct{a: 33, b: 44}).unwrap();
let deser: AlsoMyStruct = any_encoding::deserialize(&ser).unwrap();
```

where `any_encoding` is, e.g., `bincode`, `json`, or any other Serde-supported encoding. In my head, this should work nicely: the two structures have the same name (I'm explicitly renaming `AlsoMyStruct` into `"MyStruct"`) and exactly the same fields: same field names, same field types, same order of fields.

However, I am wondering: is this is actually *guaranteed* to work? Or is there some other, corner-case, maybe platform-dependent, unforeseen piece of information that a Serde serializer/deserializer might include in the representation of `MyStruct` / `AlsoMyStruct` that could lead to the two representations being incompatible?

Comment: I do not know how bincode works, but in rust those structures are not guaranteed to be the same, you have to use `#[repr(C)]` if you want that: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html

Comment: depend of the format you choice if the format is not ordered yes like json, bincode is a little special so I would say it's should be expected to be the same with bincode.

Comment: [Remote derive](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) seems adjacent, if not strictly applicable.

Comment: actually if I understand correctly yes if rust definition of your structure doesn't change and have the same value it's should be the same serialization the format be ordered or not (using same version of course), but as jonasbb said deserialization to the exact same value is not guarantee (edge case)

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, you cannot expect this to work. The reason is that neither serde nor any de/serializers guarantee that you can round-trip your data ([source](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1690#issuecomment-563031432)). This means you cannot even expect this to work in all cases if you use the same struct in both places.

For example JSON cannot round-trip `Option<()>` and formats which are not self-describing like bincode, do not support untagged enums.
Nothing in the type signatures enforces round-tripping.
Here are some reasons why deserialization might fail:

- Using `skip_serializing_none` with not self-describing formats ([serde #1732](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1732)).
- Anything which calls `deserialize_any`, such as untagged, adjacently tagged, or internally tagged enums ([serde #1762](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1762)).
- Borrowing during deserialization, e.g., for `&'de str` or `&'de [u8]`. `serde_json` only supports `&'de str` if there are no escape sequences and never supports `&'de [u8]`.
- Some formats cannot serialize some types, e.g., JSON does not supports structs as map keys and bincode only supports sequences of known lengths ([bincode #167](https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode/issues/167)).
- A type only implements one of the traits (`Serializer`/`Deserializer`) or the implementations do not match, e.g., serialize as number but deserialize as string.

That being said, this *can* work under some circumstances. The structs should have the same name and the fields in the same order. The types or rather the `Serialize`/`Deserialize` implementations also need to support round-tripping. With `Option<()>` from above it also depends on the `Serializer`/`Deserializer` implementations if you can round-trip them, even if `Serialize`/`Deserialize` implementations do support it.

Many types do try to support round-tripping, since that is what most commonly is expected.

Comment: that quite an edge case, very specific to serde_json, I'm not sure that what the OP really ask.

Comment: OP is asking "is this is actually guaranteed to work" and the answer is clearly no. Often it will work in practice, but you can also deliberately break it or run into edge cases with untagged enums, flattening of structs, or using `skip_serializing_if` (breaks round-tripping bincode).

Comment: since OP didn't assert equality like in your github link I don't think it what OP ask

Comment: @Stargateur I added some examples why round-tripping might not work. This affects more than just edge cases or equality checks.

Comment: doesn't really change my point that the OP don't ask that